# Joining all PowerPoint files in folder and subfolders generating dupes

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to make the following code work but am getting not getting the expected results.

The code recursively loops through all the folders and subfolders of where the file is located and joins all the PowerPoint documents into a single file.

The thing is that at times it seems to loop twice, duplicating the set of slides after the first pass of all the files.

What could be causing such behavior?

```
Sub loopAllSubFolderSelectStartDirectory()

    Dim FSOLibrary As Object
    Dim FSOFolder As Object
    Dim folderName As String

    folderName = ActivePresentation.Path
    If Len(folderName) > 0 Then
        MsgBox ActivePresentation.Name & vbNewLine & "saved under" & vbNewLine & folderName
    Else
        MsgBox "File not saved"
    End If

    'Set the reference to the FSO Library
    Set FSOLibrary = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Another Macro must call LoopAllSubFolders Macro to start
    LoopAllSubFolders FSOLibrary.GetFolder(folderName)

End Sub

Sub LoopAllSubFolders(FSOFolder As Object)

    Dim FSOSubFolder As Object
    Dim FSOFile As Object

    'For each subfolder call the macro
    For Each FSOSubFolder In FSOFolder.subfolders
        LoopAllSubFolders FSOSubFolder
    Next

    On Error GoTo DoNext
    'For each file, print the name
    For Each FSOFile In FSOFolder.Files

        'Insert the actions to be performed on each file
        'This example will print the full file path to the immediate window
        Debug.Print FSOFile.Path

        With ActivePresentation
            .Slides.Add Index:=.Slides.Count + 1, Layout:=ppLayoutCustom
            With ActivePresentation.Slides(.Slides.Count)
                .FollowMasterBackground = False
                .Background.Fill.Solid
                .Background.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            
                .Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = FSOFile.Path
                .Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            End With
        
            .Slides.InsertFromFile FSOFile.Path, .Slides.Count
        End With

DoNext:
    Next

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't know where that typo came from! Thanks @Dai

Answer (score 0):

You should skip active presentation file:

```
With ActivePresentation
    ...
    If FSOFile.Path <> .FullName Then
        .Slides.InsertFromFile FSOFile.Path, .Slides.Count
    End If
End With
```